# How to keep a reference to another object in the parameters of the class

Tags: swift

I just start to learn Apple Swift language and can't understand:
How to keep a reference to another object in the parameters of class?

```
// List - my custom class

class RecordsList: NSObject {

    var listObj: List!

    init (inout list: List!)
    {
        self.listObj = list
    }
    func printData()
    {
        println(self.listObj.name)
    }
}


var listObject = List()
listObject.name = "FirstValue"

RL = RecordsList(&listObject)
listObject.name = "SecondValue"

RL.printData()

// I expect: "SecondValue"
// But result: FirstValue =(
```

How can I get "SecondValue"?

Comment: I actually get `"SecondValue"` with that code on Xcode 6.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift objects are generally passed by reference, and only stuff like strings, ints, ... are passed by value... (Also structs are passed by value too!!!)

That means you don't need to create a special pointer to your object... If you just pass an object you already have set a pointer to the object (not a copy)

```
class TestClass {
    var name: String?
}

class SecondTestClass {
    var testClass: TestClass?
}

var testClass = TestClass()

var secondTestClass = SecondTestClass()
secondTestClass.testClass = testClass

testClass.name = "Worked"

var stringInObject = secondTestClass.testClass?.name

NSLog("\(stringInObject)")
```

And you are done :-)